# Is there a way to divide a string with upper and lower cases?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string for example like 'BLACKorangeREDgreen' and I want to obtain 'BLACK', 'orange', 'RED', 'green' how can I do without importing libraries?
I tried to implement it but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to import libraries?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved relatively succinctly using recursion: the general idea is to emit a word when a case change is detected (see `else` below), and keeping on doing this (recursively) on the rest of the input string. We stop running when we have scanned the entire input:

```py
test_string = "BLACKorangeREDgreen"

def split_when_case_changes(test):
  """split string recursively, setting token boundaries when case changes"""
  i = 0
  while test[0].islower() == test[i].islower():
    i += 1
    if (i >= len(test)):
       yield test[0:i+1]
       break
  else:
    yield test[:i]
    yield from split_when_case_changes(test[i:])

list(split_when_case_changes(test_string))
```

However, I think that matching strings e.g. with regular expressions using `re` could lead to a more readable and less fragile solution (more capable of handling a variety of input strings).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
START, UPPER, LOWER = 0, 1, 2

def kind(char):
    return UPPER if char == char.upper() else LOWER

def chunks(string):
    token = ""
    state = START
    for char in string:
        if kind(char) == state:
            token += char
        else:
            if state != START: yield token
            token = char
            state = kind(char)
    if state != START: yield token

test_string = "BLACKorangeREDgreen"
list(chunks(test_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check when the case of the characters change:

```
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

s = list('BLACKorangeREDgreen')
characterCase = lambda a: 'l' if a in lower else 'u'

words = []
lastCharacter = None
while s:
    current = s.pop(0)
    currentCase = characterCase(current)
    if not lastCharacter:
        words.append(current)
        lastCharacter = currentCase
        continue

    if currentCase != lastCharacter:
        words.append(current)
    else:
        words[-1] = words[-1] + current
    lastCharacter = currentCase

print(words)
```

Out:

```
['BLACK', 'orange', 'RED', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a full working example require no import statement...

```
s = 'AAAccDDDvvv'
def split_size(s):
    arr =[]
    temp = s[1]
    for letter in s[1:]:
        if temp.isupper():
            if letter.isupper():
                temp +=letter
            else:
                arr.append(temp)
                temp = letter
        elif temp.islower():
            if letter.islower():
                temp +=letter
            else:
                arr.append(temp)
                temp = letter
    arr.append(temp)
    return arr
split_size(s)

Out[1]: ['AAA', 'cc', 'DDD', 'vvv']
```